# how to count number of "," in each col

Tags: r

I have a strange question. If I have some sentence, and I would like to count how many "," in each sentence, and the new variable `number`is equal to `number of , + 1`. how can I do that? Something that looks like this:

[image]

Sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(Outcome = c("Happy, New", "Year, to, you", "this", 
"is, a , very", "strange, question")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier with `str_count` to count the number of words

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Number = str_count(Outcome, "\\w+"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Outcome           Number
#  <chr>              <int>
#1 Happy, New             2
#2 Year, to, you          3
#3 this                   1
#4 is, a , very           3
#5 strange, question      2
```

If there are two or more words and the delimiter is `,`, then count the `,` and add 1

```
df %>%
   mutate(Number = str_count(Outcome, ",") + 1)
```

---

or in `base R` with `strsplit` and `lengths`

```
df$Number <- lengths(strsplit(df$Outcome, ",\\s*"))
```

Comment: what if the words between `,` are not a word, maybe two or three  words , sth that looks like ` This is , a strange, question`?

Comment: @Stataq you can count the `,` i.e. `df %>%
   mutate(Number = str_count(Outcome, ",") + 1)` or if there are spaces as well `df %>%
   mutate(Number = str_count(Outcome, "[, ]") + 1)`

Answer (score 3):

The `count.fields` function in base R is used in functions like `read.table` to determine the number of columns required for the resulting `data.frame`. You can use that here as well, though `count.fields` is designed to work on a `file` or a connection.

```
count.fields(textConnection(df$Outcome), ",")
# [1] 2 3 1 3 2
```

Given that the function is one that is used quite often, it performs pretty efficiently. However, if you're dealing with a very large string, you might want to use `stri_count_fixed` from the "stringi" package.

Here are some tests:

```
fun_cf <- function(x = df$Outcome) count.fields(textConnection(x), ",")
fun_gs <- function(x = df$Outcome) nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', x)) + 1
fun_sc <- function(x = df$Outcome) stringr::str_count(x, ",") + 1
fun_ss <- function(x = df$Outcome) lengths(strsplit(x, ",", TRUE))
fun_scf <- function(x = df$Outcome) stringi::stri_count_fixed(x, ",") + 1

string <- rep(c(df$Outcome, paste(df$Outcome, df$Outcome, sep = ",")), 1e5)
length(string)
# [1] 1000000

bench::mark(fun_cf(string), fun_gs(string), fun_sc(string),
            fun_ss(string), fun_scf(string))
## # A tibble: 5 x 13
##   expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
##   <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
## 1 fun_cf(string)  792.64ms 792.64ms     1.26     11.6MB     0        1     0
## 2 fun_gs(string)     5.28s    5.28s     0.189    19.1MB     0        1     0
## 3 fun_sc(string)  840.17ms 840.17ms     1.19     11.4MB     1.19     1     1
## 4 fun_ss(string)  830.35ms 830.35ms     1.20     11.4MB     0        1     0
## 5 fun_scf(string) 154.86ms 155.44ms     6.24     11.4MB     1.56     4     1
## # … with 5 more variables: total_time <bch:tm>, result <list>, memory <list>,
## #   time <list>, gc <list>
```

I didn't test the `gregexpr` version since [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554558/how-to-count-number-of-in-each-col#comment117654887_66554599) indicates that counting the words might not be an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
# remove all characters except comma and count them
nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', df$Outcome))+1  
#[1] 2 3 1 3 2

df$Number <- nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', df$Outcome))+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option is using `lengths` + `gregexpr`, e.g.,

```
transform(
  df,
  Number = lengths(gregexpr("\\w+", Outcome))
)
```

which gives

```
            Outcome Number
1        Happy, New      2
2     Year, to, you      3
3              this      1
4      is, a , very      3
5 strange, question      2
```